# Não consigo corrigir este erro de syntax

Tags: python, if, syntax-error, else, ciência-de-dados

Eu não estou conseguindo entender onde que está o erro que está mostrando.
Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agreço muito!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CÓDIGO:

```
if hoje = trecuperacao:
ncasos = newrecp_list(hoje-trecuperacao)
else:
    newrecp_list = 0
```

VARIAVEIS:

trecuperacao = 4

hoje = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

ncasos = s * encontrosd * periodoinfc

s = 100-1

encontrosd = 0.1

periodoinfc = 0.1

newrecp_list=()
#novos recuperados

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: Está fazendo uma atribuição ou comparação? Se quer comparar deveria utilizar `==`. Veja na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) uma lista de operadores válidos para fazer comparação.

Comment: Perdão minha falta de conhecimento. Acabei de arrumar, espero que esteja correto agora.

Comment: Funcionou o código, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu if está usando apenas um igual, por isso ele está retornado um erro, existe uma pequena diferença entre atribuição e comparação em uma linguagem de programação que é definida a partir do número de iguais que você utiliza, como exemplo de atribuição:

```py
# Quando utilizando apenas '=' estamos dizendo para o python atribuir aquele valor para a variável
variavel1 = 1
variavel2 = 2
```

Agora quando vamos fazer um comparação no if, essa sintaxe muda um pouco, podemos ver os exemplos abaixo:

```py
valor = 5
if valor == 5:
   print("O valor é 5")
else:
   print("O valor não é 5")

# Outros exemplos de comparadores
# != diferente, que é aplicado a todo o valor que é diferente do comparado
# >= maior ou igual, ele vai aceitar resultados maiores ou iguais ao do comparado
# <= menor ou igual, ele vai aceitar resultados menores ou iguais ao do comparado
# < menor, ele vai aceitar resultados menores que o do valor comparado
# > maior, ele vai aceitar resultados maiores que o do valor comparado
```

Espero ter ajudado com sua dúvida.

Comment: Muito obrigado Alef! Funcionou o código!

Comment: Por nada e boa sorte!